# Matrix operation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, functional-programming

I have a problem to unfold a matrix. Here is how the output of the programm should look like. I am little bit stuck.

```
unfoldMatrix :: [ [a] ] -> [a]
Main> unfoldMatrix [[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9],
                [10, 11, 12]]
[1,4,7,10,11,12,9,6,3,2,5,8]
```

My code works but it's output is in this format

[[1,4,7],[8,9],[6,3],[2],[5],[]]

Any ideat how to change the code to work as wanted?

```
transpose2:: [[a]]->[[a]]
transpose2 ([]:_) = []
transpose2 x = (map head x) : transpose2 (map tail x)


unfoldMatrix:: [[a]]->[[a]]
unfoldMatrix ([]:_) = []
unfoldMatrix x =(map head x):unfoldMatrix(tail2(x))

rotate90 :: [ [ a ] ] -> [ [ a ] ]
rotate90 = (map reverse).transpose2

tail2:: [[a]]->[[a]]
tail2 = (tail).rotate90
```

Comment: hmm, you're looking for a function [that converts a list of lists to a list...](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B+%5Ba%5D+%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D)

Comment: You could simply relace the `:` in `unfoldMatrix x =(map head x):unfoldMatrix(tail2(x))` with a `++`.

Comment: I can see from your example how your unfold operation works, but can you provide a reference for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `transpose2`, if all sublists are equally long, that's the same as `transpose` from `Data.List`. So your unfold would simply be

```
Prelude Data.List> let unfold xxs@((_:_):_) = map head xxs ++ unfold (map reverse . transpose $ map tail xxs); unfold _ = []
Prelude Data.List> unfold [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[1,4,7,8,9,6,3,2,5]
Prelude Data.List> unfold [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
[1,4,7,10,11,12,9,6,3,2,5,8]
```